# Orientation of Kahati's map of the Beis Hamikdash

Tags: jewish-books, beis-hamikdash, mishna, geography

R' Kahati's map of the Beis Hamikdash - that is printed just before the beginning of Meseches Midos - has South at the top and North at the bottom. I have always found this a little confusing, being used to maps being oriented with North at the top. Is there any reason for this?

[image: Picture]

I note that the map of the complete Har Habayis that is printed on on the previous page of Meseches Midos has West at the top. Perhaps the reason for this is to fit the rectangular Har Habayis on one printed page.

Comment: The reason to have West at the  top is because West is where the Kodesh haKodoshim was.

Comment: Where - in chazal - do we ever find that north is on top ? Maybe south in the top?

Comment: @פרי זהב - indeed - that is underpinning my question!

Comment: @פריזהב R' Kehati was born a hundred years ago, well after north oriented upward on the page became conventional.

Comment: Maybe so that the Kodesh Kodashim is on the right, making the orientation more similar to a modern schul in chu"l, where the aron is on the east (right) side